# RTK Query stuck at isFetching

Tags: redux-toolkit, rtk-query

Problem: API call using RTK Query is stuck in isFetching status

I have a component **ShowSubscriptions**. There's an API call inside. It always goes to same endpoint, but with different parameters in query string, based on component props.

```js
function ShowSubscriptions({ lessonId, isActive }: IShowSubscriptions) {
  const isMobile = useMobile();
  const query = isActive ? { isActive } : { dateTo: { $lte: Date.now() } };

  const { data, isError, isSuccess } = useFindSubscriptionsQuery({
    lesson: lessonId,
    ...query,
  });

  ....
```

Here is my functions, that returns **useFindSubscriptionsQuery** hook:

```js
export function injectFind<T>(name: string, tag: any, route: string) {
  const extendedApi = basicApi.injectEndpoints({
    endpoints: (build) => ({
      [name]: build.query<IResponse<Array<T>>, Partial<T> | { [key: string]: any } >({
        query: (query) => ({ url: `${route}/find`, params: { findQuery: JSON.stringify(query) } }),
        providesTags: [tag],
      }),
    }),
  });
  return extendedApi;
}
```

I have two **ShowSubscriptions** components on same page. First component renders on page load, second renders after clicking *Show expired subscriptions* button.
[user interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cDcW.png)

**Problem** that second component is stuck in isFetching mode. It's always isFetching and never becomes isSuccess, never updates data. This is what i see in console:

```
  isActive: false // second call with isActive=false prop 
  isFetching: true // remains always true
  isError: false
  isSuccess: false // remains always false
```

On network tab in browser i see successfull response from server and I can log response using  [transfromResponse](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/createApi#transformresponse) function inside my endpoint query as well

I supposed that it could be a cache problem and based on https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/cache-behavior tried to add unique token to query params in different ways (passing string instead of an object to hook, passing  token inside query function). But it didn't help as well.

Please, advise what I'm doing wrong and how i can get fetched data in my second component.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you see a network request happening? Any errors on the console?

Comment: Yes, everything is fine here, I see this request on network tab, no erros in console. I got response as expected. I've also been able to read response in transformResponse function when added it in debug purpose to injected endpoint.

Comment: Is the query argument changing with every rerender by any chance? Like, you have something like a current timestamp in there? In that case it would keep making new requests and never finish.

Comment: @phry you catched it, thank you! Yes, problem was in timestamp, that I used for query string. Once I took timestamp out of component - request finished & state updated.  Problem solved.

But well, that's a bit unexpected behavior. Since I've seen only one request on network tab. Looks like request fired just once.

Comment: It *should* have fired a ton of requests, not sure why you saw only one. But I'm glad you found it!

Answer (score 1):

Problem **solved**. Kudos to [@phry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2075944/phry)

Error was in component, where I've invoked an API call.

```js
function ShowSubscriptions({ lessonId, isActive }: IShowSubscriptions) {
  const isMobile = useMobile();
  const query = isActive ? { isActive } : { dateTo: { $lte: Date.now() } };

  const { data, isError, isSuccess } = useFindSubscriptionsQuery({
    lesson: lessonId,
    ...query,
  });

  ....
```

`Date.now()` changed at every component rerender. That lead that query request string passed to changed every time & request stuck in infinite fetching.

**Solution:** moved timestamp out of component / do not change querystring at every component rerender.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone facing this same issue and does not want to remove their implementation of `Date.now()` as mentioned by @Ivan, you can just memoize the result.

In my case, I have a `combinedString` variable, that uses the `Date.now()` method. So I just memoized the combinedString with react's `useMemo()` hook.

```
const userId = useMemo(() => combinedString, [])
```

then you pass the result to your query, depending on your case.

```
const getUserQuery = useGetUserQuery(userId, {skip: !userId})
```