# RTK Query response comes but sometimes use hook is stuck at isFetching = true

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, redux-toolkit, react-functional-component, rtk-query

I've seen [RTK Query stuck at isFetching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75776299/rtk-query-stuck-at-isfetching) and I don't have a query that changes.

I have two queries accessed by `useMyQueryName` in my component, I see the response being returned correctly at `responseHandler` in my API created by `createApi`, though in my component the queries are both stuck like the following:

```
currentData: undefined
data: undefined
isError: false
isFetching: true
isLoading: true
isSuccess: false
isUninitialized: false
refetch: ƒ () { … }
status: 'pending'
```

Everything else works, the queries have valid responses, and it *sometimes* works too. I've yet to find a pattern. I've also put breakpoints and logs into my main component, it's *not* stuck in a render loop or something like that. My queries don't even have any inputs so it can't be a changing input anyway.

Why are queries stuck at fetching in my component whereas they're actually ready with correct data?

Comment: If you can create a small repository that shows that error, please submit a ticket in the GitHub issue tracker

Comment: @phry it doesn't occur in isolation. in simple settings everything works perfectly, as in many other components which I use the exact same pattern. there is probably a nasty edge case which I can't replicate normally. I'm still trying to eliminate by commenting out other code in an attempt to find the exact cause. will update if I do.

Comment: That would be great! We get very sporadic reports on something like this, but so far we haven't gotten a reproduction yet, so it's pretty much impossible for us to debug it.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue. In my case, there was a `resetApiState()` triggered somewhere at the same time `useQuery()` was called, making `useQuery()` stuck at loading state forever.

My solution was just simply remove that `resetApiState()`, the `useQuery()` has returned data normally.